# proxy server to intercept downloads

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

Is an Apache server a good choice to set up in order to be able to intercept all file downloads from a network (acting as a proxy server)?

Also, I'm trying to return a different file to the user. For example a user request a .pdf file and the proxy server intercepts the download and returns a text file to the user. Is Apache capable of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Squid, not Apache, to do so.

Or, if users are hitting your webserver to download files stored in it, you could create a script written in PHP, perl or whatever to control that for you.

Comment: the server isn't storing files itself, the goal is to intercept a download and instead of the real file, returning a generated textfile with some extracted metadata in it